# org.json4s.package$MappingException: Can't convert JObject

Tags: json, scala, json4s

Here is my `case class`

```
case class WorkOrderItem(configName: String,
                         logSource: File,
                         logType: String,
                         afterProcessingFileAction: String,
                         recursiveFind: Boolean = false,
                         processZipFiles: Boolean = false) {

}
```

My `JSON` looks like

```
[
  {
    "configName": "bluecoat",
    "logSource": "/root/fw1/logs/bc",
    "logType": "bluecoat",
    "recursiveFind": true,
    "processZipFiles": false,
    "afterProcessingFileAction": "delete"
  },
  {
    "configName": "mcAfee",
    "logSource": "/root/fw1/logs/mcafee",
    "logType": "mcafee",
    "recursiveFind": true,
    "processZipFiles": true,
    "afterProcessingFileAction": "delete"
  }
]
```

I wrote a custom serializer as

```
class FileSerializer extends CustomSerializer[WorkOrderItem](format => ( {
    case JObject(JField("configName", JString(configName)) ::
      JField("logSource", JString(logSource)) ::
      JField("logType", JString(logType)) ::
      JField("afterProcessingFileAction", JString(afterProcessingFileAction)) ::
      JField("recursiveFind", JBool(recursiveFind)) ::
      JField("processZipFiles", JBool(processZipFiles)) ::
      Nil) =>
      new WorkOrderItem(configName, new File(logSource), logType, afterProcessingFileAction, recursiveFind, processZipFiles)
  }, {
    case x: WorkOrderItem => ???
  }
    ))
```

When I run this as

```
object WorkOrderParser {

  class FileSerializer extends CustomSerializer[WorkOrderItem](format => ( {
    case JObject(JField("configName", JString(configName)) ::
      JField("logSource", JString(logSource)) ::
      JField("logType", JString(logType)) ::
      JField("afterProcessingFileAction", JString(afterProcessingFileAction)) ::
      JField("recursiveFind", JBool(recursiveFind)) ::
      JField("processZipFiles", JBool(processZipFiles)) ::
      Nil) =>
      new WorkOrderItem(configName, new File(logSource), logType, afterProcessingFileAction, recursiveFind, processZipFiles)
  }, {
    case x: WorkOrderItem => ???
  }
    ))


  implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints) + new FileSerializer

  def get(workOrderJson: File): List[WorkOrderItem] = {
    parse(workOrderJson).extract[List[WorkOrderItem]]
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val items: List[WorkOrderItem] = WorkOrderParser.get(new File("resources/workConfigSample.json"))
    items.foreach((x: WorkOrderItem) => println(x.afterProcessingFileAction))
  }
}
```

I get error as

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json4s.package$MappingException: Can't convert JObject(List((configName,JString(bluecoat)), (logSource,JString(/root/fw1/logs/bc)), (logType,JString(bluecoat)), (recursiveFind,JBool(true)), (processZipFiles,JBool(false)), (afterProcessingFileAction,JString(delete)))) to class com.logprocessor.processor.workOrder.WorkOrderItem
    at org.json4s.CustomSerializer$$anonfun$deserialize$1.applyOrElse(Formats.scala:385)
    at org.json4s.CustomSerializer$$anonfun$deserialize$1.applyOrElse(Formats.scala:382)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.applyOrElse(Map.scala:59)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.org$json4s$Extraction$$customOrElse(Extraction.scala:572)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$ClassInstanceBuilder.result(Extraction.scala:559)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:394)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$CollectionBuilder$$anonfun$6.apply(Extraction.scala:403)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$CollectionBuilder$$anonfun$6.apply(Extraction.scala:403)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:273)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$CollectionBuilder.mkCollection(Extraction.scala:403)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$CollectionBuilder.result(Extraction.scala:423)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:377)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:43)
    at org.json4s.ExtractableJsonAstNode.extract(ExtractableJsonAstNode.scala:21)
    at com.logprocessor.processor.workOrder.WorkOrderParser$.get(WorkOrderParser.scala:29)
    at com.logprocessor.processor.workOrder.WorkOrderParser$.main(WorkOrderParser.scala:33)
    at com.logprocessor.processor.workOrder.WorkOrderParser.main(WorkOrderParser.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!

Answer (score 1):

It's happened because the order of fields violated.

Comment: Sooo what's the fix?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, there is a workaround you can use to prevent the order of the json from mattering. After all json is unstructured data so it is good to be able to handle the object properties in any order by replacing the custom serializer with the following:

```
import org.json4s.CustomSerializer
import org.json4s.JsonAST._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._



class WorkOrderItemSerializerUnordered extends CustomSerializer[WorkOrderItem](format => ( {
  case jsonObj: JObject =>
    val configName = (jsonObj \ "configName").extract[String]
    val logSource = (jsonObj \ "logSource").extract[String]
    val logType = (jsonObj \ "logType").extract[String]
    val afterProcessingFileAction = (jsonObj \ "afterProcessingFileAction").extract[String]
    val recursiveFind = (jsonObj \ "recursiveFind").extract[Boolean]
    val processZipFiles = (jsonObj \ "processZipFiles").extract[Boolean]
    new WorkOrderItem(configName, new File(logSource), logType, afterProcessingFileAction, recursiveFind, processZipFiles)
}, {
  case wi: WorkOrderItem =>
    ("configName" -> wi.configName) ~
      ("logSource" -> wi.logSource) ~
      ("logType" -> wi.logType) ~
      ("afterProcessingFileAction" -> wi. afterProcessingFileAction) ~
      ("recursiveFind" -> wi.recursiveFind) ~
      ("processZipFiles" -> wi.processZipFiles) 
}
))
```

here is the link where I found this suggestion at:
https://nmatpt.com/blog/2017/01/29/json4s-custom-serializer/